# Enabling specific cipher suite in C#

Tags: c#

We are trying to upload a file to a device or download a file from a device using a C# WPF application. We are using .Net Framework 4.5 to achieve this. The device in question supports only two protocols, namely:

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

After analysis, we found these two cipher suites are supported under TLS1.2. We are currently using the below code to enable TLS1.2 in .Net Framework 4.5:

***ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;***

But as we all know TLS1.2 supports many cipher suites. We want to enable only the above cipher suites.

Can anyone please us if there is any way to enable only those two cipher suites?
And also please let us know if the above line of code is sufficient to enable TLS1.2 in a C# application.

Comment: Why you want to do this? On the client side should supports all of cipher suites.

Comment: They need us to support only these two, so wanted to check if this is possible in C#.